# Using libMPSSE with FT4232H in Linux

Tags: linux, spi, ftdi

I don't have much experience with the FT4232H.
It is quad a port device.
I want to configure some of the ports as SPI, other as UART and GPIO

I have started experimenting with the SPI .
In the official documentation it says that if ftd2xx and libMPSSE are used
one have to remove the standard kernel modules ftdi_sio and usbserial so I did it.

My question:
In Linux can I have all 4 port configured arbitrary as SPI/UART/I2C/GPIO
as each port uses possibly different driver in the PC?
As far as I know the driver is loaded based on the PID/VID.
It is unique for the FT4232H which has 4 ports, so how this can be done?
Any thought about this is welcome.

I also want to share my current (one day) experience with the libMPSSE.
Unfortunately kind of negative.
I have downloaded the source code for the latest libMPSSE-rev0.6 from the official FTDI web site.
I was surprised to see that no provisioning for compilation under Linux.
There is no Makefile for the libMPSSE. I have made a simple one which is not a big deal but then I found out it does not compile out of the box. I got "undefined type byte" at one location.
After building the library I have done a simple test application which behaved strange.
I was sending 8 bytes on the SPI but with the oscilloscope I was observing 7 8bit clock packets then 100us pause and finally the last 8 bit packet. The MOSI also was incorrect in the last packet.(I was sending all 0 but got two bits high at the end)
Luckily I found https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/518039-ftdi-libmpsse-0-6-spi_readwrite-weird-behaviour-loadlibrary-calllib .
Fixing that made my transfer looks OK.
It looks to me FTDI have not done even a basic check of libMPSSE

I can not understand how FTDI so popular chips can have that low quality software library.
Probably ftd2xx is OK and issues are only in the higher layer libMPSSE?
Anyone using libMPSSE? Should I expect more issues?
Any thoughts about FTDI solution stability is welcome.

Thanks
Dimitar

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

In my understanding, large part of your "question" is not really a question but a "discussion starting point" which is not the scope of the "stack-..." ecosystem.

To the driver question part:
To the best of my knowledge, the driver is loaded once per device and not per port. However, the ftd2xx is able to address each port individually and set them to different modes (basically it simple gives the specific orders to the MPSSE engine which does not really care about the real meaning of the given sequences). Only thing you lose is the convinent VCP accessability.

The different libMPSSE modes have their limitations and quirks. A website search will yield more than enough as a starting point for more narrowed down follow-up questions. If you are only interested in one mode, an IC dedicated to only this mode might be an alternative to the relatively "generic" FTx232x serie.